# How to cancel Firebase Storage Metadata download Task?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I intermittently check if there is a new version of a file on Firebase Storage on my app. I use:

```
val task = ref.metadata
        task.addOnSuccessListener
```

To check the metadata and compare it to my existing download. I have an issue with a leak, where, if the user has no or bad connection it maintains the call. There is no method to cancel the request.

How can I remove the failed request to prevent memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from your question, you are trying to retrieve the metadata that is associated with your "ref" object, and if something has changed, download the file again.

If that's the case, in order to be able to cancel the download operation when the user has no, or bad internet connection, please try the solution below.

When you get the changed file using:

```
val task = ref.getFile(destinationFile)
```

Please note that [getFile(File destinationFile)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getFile(java.io.File)) method that is called on a [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) object, returns an object of type [FileDownloadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask). This class is a subclass of [StorageTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTask), which in terms is a subclass of [ControllableTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/ControllableTask), which is also a subclass of [CancellableTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/CancellableTask).

Because of the inheritance relationship between these three classes, you can simply call CancellableTask's [cancel()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/CancellableTask#cancel()) method:

> Attempts to cancel the task.

In order to cancel the Task. In code should look like this:

```
task.cancel()
```

Since Kotlin is a statically typed programming language where the variable types are determined at compile-time and **not** at run-time, you can use `val` or `var` when defining a variable, instead of the type of the object. This makes it sometimes hard to read the object type. So since you cannot declare the above variable, as we did in earlier versions in Java:

```
FileDownloadTask task = ref.getFile(destinationFile);
```

A more readable way of decraling the above object would be:

```
val fileDownloadTask = ref.getFile(destinationFile)
```

And to cancel the Task:

```
fileDownloadTask.cancel()
```

It should be more understandable now.

**Edit:**

The Firebase Android SDK for Cloud Storage doesn't support offline access, hence that behavior. You can cancel() an operation when reading a file, or resume the operation when uploading a file, when the user has no, or bad internet connection, but not when reading the metadata.

The best option I can think of is to save the URL of the file together with some important metadata into [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and use a persistent listener to get updates in real-time.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer! That is perfect for a file download task, but when getting metadata via the StorageRef .getMetadata() method, there is no cancel method. My question is in relation to getting metadata not a file.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, there is no cancel() method when getting the Metadata. This is happening because StorageReference's [getMetadata()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getMetadata()), returns a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) object, and as you can see there is no such a method. Besides that, the Task class extends only the Object class and **not** any other class. So it doesn't inherit a similar method. So the read operation of the metadata cannot be canceled.

Comment: Ahh okay. That is what is causing the memory leak for me, as its calling, doesn't return an error for not being online, it just maintains the task. I have a hard coded "isInternetAvailable" check added, but it doesn't help for weak connections where the leak can maintain for a longer period. Any ideas of a workaround?

Comment: I cannot see how getting some metadata might leak memory. However, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same regarding saving something to the database. Could work, but maybe less than ideal. I was getting reports of a memory leak from leak canary definitively blaming getMetadata(). I will experiment further.

Comment: In that case, the best option that you have is to save that data in one of the available databases.

Comment: How can I determine when to cancel the upload task, since no exception is thrown? Ideally, I would like to find a direct solution without having to create additional methods to check for internet connectivity.

Comment: I turned off my internet connection and tried to upload an image, but I did not receive any error message from Firebase Storage. After waiting for 5-10 minutes and turning the internet back on, the image was uploaded automatically. Is there a way to throw an exception in case of no internet connection? If so, I hope edit your answer and provide a clear explanation. I am using the putFile() method for uploading the image. A 50 point bounty will be awarded if there is an easy solution.

Comment: @TahaSami You can cancel the upload task when you need it to be canceled. The absence of the internet doesn't throw an exception and unfortunately, you cannot change this behavior. Firebase is designed to work offline.