# Preventing Pending Writes in Firebase with Transactions Not Working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I aim to insert the name in Cloud Firestore when the button is clicked, but I don't want the save to be pending if the user is not connected to the internet. I don't like the behavior of Firebase where it saves pending writes, even if the internet connection is restored.

I researched and found that [Firebase developers suggest using transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308344/how-can-i-discard-pending-documentreference-writes-when-offline/54308526#54308526) to prevent pending writes when there is no internet. I have tried this, but the result is still the same: if there is no internet, it saves pending writes, and when the internet connection is restored, it rewrites to Firestore. Why aren't transactions working as expected?

```
HashMap < String, Object > hashMap = new HashMap < > ();
hashMap.put("Name", "Test");

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().batch().set(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("LISTS").document(), hashMap).commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + task, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (task.isSuccessful())
            activityMainBinding.activityMainMaterialToolbarTopBar.setTitle("Done");
        else
            activityMainBinding.activityMainMaterialToolbarTopBar.setTitle(task.getException().getMessage());
    }
});
```

I am short on time as I want to deliver this project to the company on the specified date, and I don't want to waste time. If it's not possible to solve the problem with transactions, please let me know so I can look for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using [FirebaseFirestore#batch()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#batch()) you aren't performing a transaction, but creating a [WriteBatch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/WriteBatch):

> Creates a write batch, used for performing multiple writes as a single atomic operation.

So, it's an atomic operation and not a transaction. If you need to perform a transaction, please check the official documentation below:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

So you should use [FirebaseFirestore#runTransaction()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#runTransaction(com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.Function%3CTResult%3E)) which:

> Executes the given updateFunction and then attempts to commit the changes applied within the transaction.

Comment: I understand that `FirebaseFirestore#runTransaction()` is necessary when I have both read and write operations on documents, while WriteBatch is used for write-only operations. In my case, as I only need to write documents, I used WriteBatch. However, I am a bit confused about the differences between the two. Can you provide more information about runTransaction and WriteBatch? I will try your solution and get back to you.

Comment: Transactions require round-trip communication with the Firebase server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully. Without an internet connection that is not possible. On the other hand, a batch operation allows you to perform multiple different operations (set, update, delete) at different locations, no matter if you have a connection or not. It's true it's an atomic operation, but it's not a transaction.

Comment: Yep, give it a try and tel me if it works.

Comment: It has worked and it's a great solution. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to cancel pending writes to Firebase Storage if there was no internet? I'm experiencing the same issue now with Firebase Storage.

Comment: For sure there is. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68563672/how-to-cancel-firebase-storage-metadata-download-task/68571583#68571583).